# Custom rendering of a taxonomy - without using HTML lists

Tags: orchardcms

I have a multi-layer taxonomy that I want to display in a Bootstrap 'row/column' layout. How do I stop Orchard from rendering it as an HTML list?

At present I am having to create alternates at quite a high level. So far:

```
1. Parts.TaxonomyPart-url-MyTaxonomy
2. TaxonomyItem-MyTaxonomy
3. TaxonomyItemLink-MyTaxonomy
```

The first is required to remove the main `<ul>` that is automatically added by Orchard.

The second removes the `<ul>` from any child terms

The third handles the display of the actual taxonomy term (my custom HTML).

It works, but I'm sure there's a less cluttered way of doing it that I can't see.

I would prefer to alter the rendering of the taxonomy this way rather than create a projection, as I find projections don't handle taxonomies with hierarchies very well / easily.

Any help / suggestions would be much appreciated! Comment if you need more info.